# Database not updated bug - Entity Framework

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using a Entity Framework and JQuery to update values in an SQL table column with a bit data type. This is being done by reading the values into an html table and then having a button that will change the bit value for each row.

Here you can see the html table:

```
    <table id="categoryList" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Category ID</th>
        <th>Category Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Categories)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.id</td>
            <td>@item.name</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-success categoryEnabled" data-id="@item.id">Enabled</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then here is the script I am using to start the action on click:

```
$(".categoryEnabled").on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $(this).next().show();
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    e.cancelBubble = true;
    if (e.stopPropagation) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
    DisableRow($(this).data('id'));
});

function DisableRow(id) {
    $.post('@Url.Action("DisableRow", "Category")', { "Id": id }, function () {
        alert('Row Disabled!');
    }).fail(function () {
        alert('Error disabling row!');
    });
}
```

This is then linked to a controller action that should change the state bit value for the selected row and update:

```
public void DisableRow(int id)
    {
        var connection = new CategoryDBEntities();

        var record = connection.Categories.Find(id);

        if (record == null) return;

        record.state = StatesTypes.Disabled;

        connection.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Here's Category object for reference:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    public enum StatesTypes
    {
        Disabled = 0,
        Enabled = 1
    }

public partial class Category
{

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public StatesTypes state { get; set; }
}
```

}

DbContext:

```
namespace Project.Models
{
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class CategoryDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public QualityDBEntities()
        : base("name=CategoryDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

}
```

}

Output from Diagnostics Debug:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name]
FROM [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[id] = @p0


-- p0: '5' (Type = Int32)
```

The issue is that the record.state is changed to disabled (0), but the bit value in the database does not change. I must be missing something here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You say bit but enums usually are mapped to integers. Can you send the mapping? Also, how did you create the DB? Try to change the bit to integer

Comment: The Db was already created. I just added the state column in an existing table. I'll try to change the bit to int. If I wanted to keep it bit, what would I change the enum to?

Comment: Add the following code after the line where you new up a `CategoryDBEntities`: `connection.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);`.  This will output the SQL that EF generates when you call `SaveChanges()`.  What do you see?

Comment: How do you open the console for VS

Comment: Bits in EF get mapped to boolean not ints?  Try changing the field to a bool for state instead of an enum would be my advice.

Comment: @Cavan: If you use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` instead of `Console.WriteLine`, then you will see the information printed to the VS Output window (View --> Output).

Comment: I wrote the output at the end of the question

Comment: I tried changing the field to bool earlier and it still didnt update the database\

Comment: Did you try marking the entity state as modified?  Something along the lines of connection.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified; before saving?

Comment: Do you really have a record in your `Category` table with Id `5`?  Are you absolutely sure that the `connection.Categories.Find(id)` is returning an entity and not simply a `null` value?

Comment: Yes, I've double checked. It gets the id and shows the name.\

Comment: @Jasen: Not a bad idea as a test.  But it should not be necessary in this case, because the entity is fetched from the context.  So something else is going on.  But it's still a good test to try.

Comment: @OP: After the line `connection.Categories.Find(id)`, if you add `Debug.WriteLine(record.State)`, (before you change the state, of course) what do you get?

Comment: I get the word Disabled

Comment: @sstan you're right. I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

Your `state` column is not being mapped at all between EF and your database.

You can see this in your SQL log:

```
SELECT TOP (2) 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name]
FROM [dbo].[Category] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[id] = @p0


-- p0: '5' (Type = Int32)
```

Notice that the `state` column is not being selected at all.

Look to see if you have configured the `state` property to be ignored by using an annotation `[NotMapped]`, or fluent API configuration like `entityTypeConfiguration.Ignore(p => p.state)`.

Once you have that fixed, I expect you'll be getting exceptions about the fact that you're mapping an enum to a bit field.  As others are suggesting, you probably want to use a boolean for your property.

Answer (score 0):

I will make this an answer because I am pretty sure if you are hitting the action method at some point you will need to do this before saving changes.

```
connection.Entry(record).State = EntityState.Modified;
connection.SaveChanges();
```

This allows EF to issue an update on the record passed.  I still think you might run into issues not having the state be a boolean and trying to save to a bit field though.

Humor us and try the following:

```
public void DisableRow(int id)
{
    var connection = new CategoryDBEntities();

    var record = connection.Categories.Find(id);

    if (record == null) return;

    record.state = false; //Assume false for disabled

    connection.SaveChanges();
}
```

And

```
public partial class Category
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool state { get; set; }
}
```

I am making the assumption you are using code first to create your database, but regardless I know for a fact if you generate from an existing DB the field will be a bool if it is a bit in the db.  Something else to consider it might need to be a nullable column on the DB unless you set a default some how.  Simply replace:

```
public bool state { get; set; }
//with
public bool? state { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is a good test to try.  But it is not a correct solution, because the entity is part of the context already.  Changing the property should be sufficient.  Setting an entity to `Modified` is required when you are attaching a disconnected entity.

Comment: I still lean towards the bit not mapping correctly.  EF in my experience has always treated bit fields as boolean in code.

Comment: I tried this and it still showed no change in the database :/

Comment: See my latest update bool might need to be a nullable?

Comment: Ok let's take a step back and cover some basics:

1) You hit the DisableRow method correct (in debug)?
2) I assume the connection is working (record != null)?
3) Is the database table correctly created by code first (with bit field etc)

Comment: Also, I did need to cast to EntityState here: connection.Entry(record).State = (EntityState) System.Data.EntityState.Modified;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81567/discussion-between-shawn-and-cavan-flynn).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're actually committing the changed item back to the database. You're only altering the copy you've made of it.

To ensure that the data is altered in the DB you want to do something like the following:

```
connection.Categories.Attach(record);
connection.Entry(record).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
connection.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is a good test to try.  But it is not a correct solution, because the entity is part of the context already.  Changing the property should be sufficient.  Setting an entity to `Modified` is required when you are attaching a disconnected entity.

Comment: Hmmm...this still didn't solve the problem. Not too sure what else could be going on

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this figured out! Thanks @Shawn for all the help!

There were actually a couple things going on.

First off, like you suggested I had to change the the StatesType enum to bool so it would map correctly:

```
public partial class Category
{
public int id { get; set; }
public string name { get; set; }
public bool state { get; set; }
}
```

Since its now bool I set the state to false:

```
public void DisableRow(int id)
{
var connection = new CategoryDBEntities();

var record = connection.Categories.Find(id);

if (record == null) return;

record.state = false;

connection.SaveChanges();
}
```

The big issue here and the main reason that it wasn't showing any change in the database was because the state column was not being mapped between EF and the database (which was also referenced in one of the answers).

This was because the state column was created in SQL Server Management; not VS. So I had to go into the .edmx and click 'Update Model from Database' and then refresh the table.

Thanks for all the help on this one!